# Flutter Couldn't find "libflutter.so"

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am building an application fot hotel reservation with Flutter and Firebase, it was working well until this error started to show and app doesn't want to load in my emulator (Memu).

I have add to android/app/grandle but still doesn't work, please help!

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86_64'
        }
    }
}
```

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM N975F in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
E/FlutterLoader(11192): Flutter initialization failed.
E/FlutterLoader(11192): java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.donza.hotel_app-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.donza.hotel_app-2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so"
E/FlutterLoader(11192):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:94)
E/FlutterLoader(11192):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:164)
E/FlutterLoader(11192):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader.ensureInitializationComplete(FlutterLoader.java:200)
E/FlutterLoader(11192):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine.<init>(FlutterEngine.java:317)
E/FlutterLoader(11192):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine.<init>(FlutterEngine.java:204)
E/FlutterLoader(11192):     at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.setupFlutterEngine(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:244)
E/FlutterLoader(11192):     at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onAttach(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:155)
E/FlutterLoader(11192):     at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onCreate(FlutterActivity.java:409)
E/FlutterLoader(11192):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6727)
E/FlutterLoader(11192):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
E/FlutterLoader(11192):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2619)
E/FlutterLoader(11192):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2727)
E/FlutterLoader(11192):     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
E/FlutterLoader(11192):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1478)
E/FlutterLoader(11192):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/FlutterLoader(11192):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
E/FlutterLoader(11192):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
E/FlutterLoader(11192):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/FlutterLoader(11192):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
E/FlutterLoader(11192):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
E/FlutterLoader(11192): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.donza.hotel_app-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.donza.hotel_app-2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so"
E/FlutterLoader(11192):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:984)
E/FlutterLoader(11192):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1562)
E/FlutterLoader(11192):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.loadLibrary(FlutterJNI.java:116)
E/FlutterLoader(11192):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader$1.call(FlutterLoader.java:152)
E/FlutterLoader(11192):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader$1.call(FlutterLoader.java:147)
E/FlutterLoader(11192):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
E/FlutterLoader(11192):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
E/FlutterLoader(11192):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
E/FlutterLoader(11192):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
E/AndroidRuntime(11192): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(11192): Process: com.donza.hotel_app, PID: 11192
E/AndroidRuntime(11192): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.donza.hotel_app/com.donza.hotel_app.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.donza.hotel_app-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.donza.hotel_app-2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so"
E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2666)
E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2727)
E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1478)
E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
E/AndroidRuntime(11192): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.donza.hotel_app-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.donza.hotel_app-2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so"
E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader.ensureInitializationComplete(FlutterLoader.java:283)
E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine.<init>(FlutterEngine.java:317)
E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine.<init>(FlutterEngine.java:204)
E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.setupFlutterEngine(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:244)
E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onAttach(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:155)
E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onCreate(FlutterActivity.java:409)
E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6727)
E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2619)
E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    ... 9 more
E/AndroidRuntime(11192): Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.donza.hotel_app-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.donza.hotel_app-2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so"
E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:94)
E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:164)
E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader.ensureInitializationComplete(FlutterLoader.java:200)
E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    ... 17 more
E/AndroidRuntime(11192): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.donza.hotel_app-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.donza.hotel_app-2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so"
E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:984)
E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1562)
E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.loadLibrary(FlutterJNI.java:116)
E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader$1.call(FlutterLoader.java:152)
E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader$1.call(FlutterLoader.java:147)
E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Comment: Did you solve this error? I'm seeing it in Crashlytics after the latest release of my app.

Comment: Check out this medium post it contains the solution : https://medium.com/codechai/flutter-app-couldnt-find-libflutter-so-c95ad81cbccd

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `build.gradle` file.

```
android { ... defaultConfig { .... ndk { abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86_64' } }
```

[Reference on GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32756?utm_source=pocket_mylist#issuecomment-744301219)

Comment: already added to build.gradle. but not work.

Comment: still not working